# How to retrieve TCP packet informations given by libpcap functions on MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, networking, libpcap

I'm trying to do a packet sniffer on MacOs using libpcap functions. I'm using a code found on internet that shows how to use libpcap , the problem is that this is a code for linux and i am on macos. So I have a lot of problems in translating the different struct iphdr/struct tcphdr etc from Linux to MacOs. I succeeded for struct iphdr and struct ethhdr but I cant translate struct tcphdr.

Here is the struct tcphdr on Linux :

```
struct tcphdr {
   25     __be16  source;
   26     __be16  dest;
   27     __be32  seq;
   28     __be32  ack_seq;
   29 #if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
   30     __u16   res1:4,
   31         doff:4,
   32         fin:1,
   33         syn:1,
   34         rst:1,
   35         psh:1,
   36         ack:1,
   37         urg:1,
   38         ece:1,
   39         cwr:1;
   40 #elif defined(__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
   41     __u16   doff:4,
   42         res1:4,
   43         cwr:1,
   44         ece:1,
   45         urg:1,
   46         ack:1,
   47         psh:1,
   48         rst:1,
   49         syn:1,
   50         fin:1;
   51 #else
   52 #error  "Adjust your <asm/byteorder.h> defines"
   53 #endif  
   54     __be16  window;
   55     __sum16 check;
   56     __be16  urg_ptr;
   57 };
```

Here is the one for MacoS :

```
struct tcphdr {
    unsigned short  th_sport;   /* source port */
    unsigned short  th_dport;   /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;         /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;         /* acknowledgement number */
#if __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER == __DARWIN_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int    th_x2:4,    /* (unused) */
            th_off:4;   /* data offset */
#endif
#if __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER == __DARWIN_BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int    th_off:4,   /* data offset */
            th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
#endif
    unsigned char   th_flags;
#define TH_FIN  0x01
#define TH_SYN  0x02
#define TH_RST  0x04
#define TH_PUSH 0x08
#define TH_ACK  0x10
#define TH_URG  0x20
#define TH_ECE  0x40
#define TH_CWR  0x80
#define TH_FLAGS    (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)

    unsigned short  th_win;     /* window */
    unsigned short  th_sum;     /* checksum */
    unsigned short  th_urp;     /* urgent pointer */
};
```

The thing is that I dont know where to find the ack/doff/urg etc fields present in the Linux struct, in the MacOs struct ?
Could someone tell me where to get thoses informations ? I am not this much advanced in C to comprehend the different definitions.

Comment: Looks like 'doff' is 'th_off'. And ack/urg etc are in 'th_flags'. There are even #defines giving you the bitmasks for them.

Comment: Oh yeah, i didnt understand the purpose of th_flags. It should do the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a TCP header is defined by [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) and later specifications; they are not defined by Linux or Windows or BSD/macOS or....

Tcpdump used to depend on structures form the OS, but that caused problems when different OSes, and fifferent OS versions, had different headers, so it now has a copy of BSD headers in its own source.

If you're working with code originally written for Linux, you might want to just copy the Linux header into your own program, and just replace

```
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
```

with

```
#if __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER == __DARWIN_LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

and replace

```
#elif defined(__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
```

with

```
#elif __DARWIN_BYTE_ORDER == __DARWIN_BIG_ENDIAN
```

The Linux code is covered by the GNU Public License (GPL) version 2, so if you include it, your code will also have to be covered by that license.